# How can I find out what repository a working directory belongs to?

Tags: svn

I have a bunch of directories which are working directories of various similar repositories. How can I find out which repository they are checked out from?

I'm looking for a solution which works from the command-line on Mac and Linux systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svn info wc` where `wc` is the path to the working copy you want to find out.  You'll get two fields that may be useful.

URL: The full URL to the path you asked for (which might be some file under your wc).

Repository Root: The URL to the root of the repository the WC is from.

There is an `--xml` option if you want that as well.